# The connection with the debugger has been lost

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have recently updated the Xamarin Android (Version 4.5.0.443). When I deploy the code via Visual Studio, app installation success but I cannot debug due to the following issue.

Has anyone have any idea(s)?

```
The connection with the debugger has been lost. The target application may have exited.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Cecil.Mdb, Version=0.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Mono.Cecil.Mdb, Version=0.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.CheckBetterMatch(TypeMirror type, String file, Int32 line, Int32 column, Location found)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.FindLocationByMethod(MethodMirror method, String file, Int32 line, Int32 column, Boolean& insideTypeRange)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.FindLocationByType(TypeMirror type, String file, Int32 line, Int32 column, Boolean& genericMethod, Boolean& insideTypeRange)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.ResolveBreakpoints(TypeMirror type)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleTypeLoadEvents(TypeLoadEvent[] events)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEventSet(EventSet es)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.EventHandler()
```

The following packages are included into my project
[image]

Comment: [Are you trying to use this library](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil)? Google the what appears to be a package name

Comment: I have added packages into my question, please check.

Comment: As far as I understand, the debugger experiences an error. Restart your IDE(and maybe computer), and try to debug again

Comment: I have restarted IDE and machine couple of times already.

Comment: That does not happen only for this project, that happens for other projects as well. These projects were working in debug mode, but after the update this issue appears.

Comment: Try restarting the device. (If it is an emulator, close the window)

Comment: If you are using the visual studio emulator for android shut down the emulator and open up the hyper-v settings.  Find the emulator and under processor make sure the compatibility check box is checked.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem since the Xamarin 15.2 update. Same symptoms occur on both Android and iOS projects. I've not found anything helpful on Xamarin forums. I've filed a bug against the release - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56503

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after I uninstalled [mono](https://download.mono-project.com/archive/6.12.0/windows-installer/mono-6.12.0.107-x64-0.msi) which i had installed while trying to check ot how the MonoDevelop IDE felt. I re-installed it and the error was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with latest Xamarin update, I am using Visual Studio 2015 and the problem is solved after installing Visual Studio update 3.