# I'm getting an error when running the .Net Maui project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, maui

When I run the .NET MAUI project, I get an error like the picture below. I would be happy if you help.
I researched on the internet to solve the problem, but I could not find a solution.
[image: Error Message]

I don't know what I can do to solve this error.

Comment: Post your error as message, not picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:

1.try to delete the bin folders and the obj folders and rebuild it. If it doesn’t work, try to restart the VS.

2.If the problem persist, try to repair your visual studio.
For more information, check document: [Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

And there is a similar thread,you can check it up here: [The connection with the debugger has been lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944266/the-connection-with-the-debugger-has-been-lost).